# Row level policy doesn't work on my table

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

I have a table which I'm trying to apply a policy on, the setup looks something like this:

```
create role anonymous nologin;
create schema api;
create schema private;
create table private.mytable(
    id  serial primary key,
    description text default ''
);
create view api.mytable as select * from private.mytable;
insert into api.mytable (description) values ('row 1'), ('row 2');
grant usage on schema api to anonymous;
grant select on api.mytable to anonymous;
alter table private.mytable enable row level security;
create policy mytable_policy on private.mytable
    for select
    using (null);
```

When I set the role to `anonymous` and select all records from `mytable`:

```
set role anonymous;
select * from api.mytable;
```

I excpect no rows to be returned since my expression in the `using` clause in the policy is `null` but I get everything.
I tried different `postgresql` versions (9.5, 9.6, 10.3) but they all have the same behaviour, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Does it work if you use `using (false)`?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: where did you try it?.. real db or some fiddle?..

Comment: I tried both connecting to a remote server and setting up a docker instance of postgres. @VaoTsun

Comment: try `alter view api.mytable owner to anonymous ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33863371/5315974

RLS won't work with views like that. You can use RLS for views though it is limited.

what you can do is

```
alter view api.mytable owner to anonymous ;
```

Comment: Using your exact commands I cannot reproduce it, but try my script from the question. I see the differences are that you started a transaction with BEGIN, and that you're granting permissions to anonymous on the private schema (which I don't want to do).

Comment: I fixed typos and added missing permissions. the rest is exactly your script - no?..

Comment: No, you did the select on the private table rather than the public view: select * from private.mytable;  It seems that policies do not apply on views too.

Comment: ues! indeed. now I see what you mean :) look here then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858030/why-isnt-row-level-security-enabled-for-postgres-views

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: sure, my pleasure