# Is possible to create row level security policy for a postgresql view?

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-9.5, row-level-security

We need to implement **row-level security policy** for a **PostgreSQL View**. Is there any option to do this?

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't row level security enabled for Postgres views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858030/why-isnt-row-level-security-enabled-for-postgres-views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW
  view_own_log
AS SELECT
  these,
  fields,
  only
FROM
  restricted_log_table
WHERE
  username=user;
```

`user` is the logged on user.

You can create more sophisticated `WHERE` clauses if needed. Have the table access limited to minimum and use `GRANT` to give access to the view.